# Change the text size of post body in the blogger homepage (i.e of the snippet)

Tags: blogger

I am trying to change the size of the text of the post body i.e of the snippet shown in the homepage. In the default theme there is an option to change the size of the text of the body, which I did. It changes the size of the text in the post. What I want is the size of the text in individual posts to remain as provided by the default option but in the homepage, I want to change it.

**What I did so far?**

I tried to modify the HTML and added two lines which are given below:

```
<Variable name="posts.stream.text.font" description="Post text stream font"
type="font"
default="$(robotoBold20)"  value="normal bold 30px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"/>
```

and

```
<Variable name="robotoBold20" description="Roboto Bold 20" type="font" 
default="bold 20px Roboto, sans-serif" hideEditor="true"  value="bold 20px Roboto, sans-serif"/>
```

I added the first line with the existing block

```
<Group description="Posts" selector="div.widget.Blog">
```

The second line is added with some similar lines in the theme.

However, it still doesn't change the text font size in the homepage. What am I doing wrong and what is the proper way to change the size of the post body in the homepage i.e in the homepage snippet?

Theme used : Contempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem by trial and error. As I am not familiar much with CSS, this is probably the not the best way to do this. Also, I am sure this can be done in a better way. I welcome answers to this question, which includes modification of this code.

Here is my code:

```
.Blog .blog-posts .post-outer-container .post-outer .container.post-body.entry-content .post-snippet.snippet-container.r-snippet-container .snippet-item.r-snippetized{
font-size: 18px;
}

.r-snippetized{
font-size: 18px;
}
```

PS: I do feel I did something redundant.